# Rasterization of polygon with area variable

Tags: python, r, rasterio, rasterization, terra

The usual approach for rasterizing polygons/vectors is to take the values of polygons inside a grid cell and combine them somehow. This works well for field attributes that are not proportional to the polygon area, such as production, yield, temperature, precipitation.

However, I have not found cases in which the field attribute or variable is related to the area of the polygon. Metrics such as area or volumes are deeply connected to the original size of the polygon, and simply extending them to each grid cell would imply in distortions. In my view, the more suited approach for this case would be to take into account the fraction of the polygon inside the grid cell and then sum all polygons inside the same grid cell to obtain the rasterised area. Looking across the main packages of rasterization in both R and Python, I've failed to spot any method that could address this issue. Would anyone be aware of anything on this matter?

As example to illustrate my problem:

Traditional approach of rasterization: "In each grid cell, weight average all polygons values proportionally to their presence in the grid cell"

What I am looking for: "For each polygon part in each grid cell, calculate the fraction of the polygon inside the grid cell (wrt to the total polygon area) and SUM all values inside the grid cell".

To give more objective examples would be a bit troublesome, but if required I can try to. I can use both R (terra, raster, rdgal) or Python (Rasterio, Xarray, Geocube).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terra::rasterize function has a cover argument and raster::rasterize has a getCover argument. If set to TRUE the function will return the fraction of the intersecting polygon. Using `exact_extract` in exactextractr library, you can directly return fractional intersection or use a weights raster to derive weighted sum or mean.

First add libraries and data. We will create some polygons (based on buffered centroids) and a random raster to act as our example.

```
library(terra)
library(sf)
library(exactextractr)

f <- st_read(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
  r <- rast(vect(f), ncols=100, nrows=100)
    r[] <- runif(ncell(r))
b <- st_buffer(st_centroid(f), 2500)
```

Here we create a raster of polygon fractional polygon cover for each cell. You could simply use this as a scalar.

```
p <- rasterize(vect(b), r, cover=TRUE)
```

We can convert our raster into a fishnet and using `exact_extract` and out raster of polygon fractional cover as weights, get our weighted sum. We then rasterize our results.

```
g <- st_as_sf(as.polygons(r, dissolve=FALSE))
g$wsum <- exact_extract(r, g, 'weighted_sum', weights=p)
  g <- rasterize(vect(g), r, "wsum")
    head(g[!is.na(g)])

# 0.03099 0.10215 0.69101 0.31077 0.80389 0.41426


par(mfrow=c(1,2))
  plot(r, legend=FALSE)
    plot(st_geometry(b), add=TRUE)
  plot(g, legend=FALSE)
    plot(st_geometry(b), add=TRUE)
```

[image: fractional sum]

If you want the polygons rasterized in a uniform manner, you can calculate the raster fractions directly, This is probably the most efficient way to do this as you can assign the weighted sum to the polygons and then rasterize the adjusted values.

```
e <- exact_extract(r, b)
  e <- lapply(e, function(x) {
    sum(x[,1] * x[,2], na.rm=TRUE)
  })
```

Here are the unweighted and fractional weighted sums.

```
extract(r, vect(b), sum)[,2] # unweighted sums
unlist(e)                    # weighted sums
```

Now, assign the weighted sums to the polygons and rasterize.

```
b$wsum <- unlist(e)
  g <- rasterize(vect(b), r, "wsum")

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
  plot(r, legend=FALSE)
    plot(st_geometry(b), add=TRUE)
  plot(g, legend=FALSE)
    plot(st_geometry(b), add=TRUE)
```

[image: uniform weighted sums]

Comment: You can also use density: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71831527/635245